# How to increase precision: $MinPrecision does not help

Tags: plotting, arbitrary-precision

I have the following series:

```
f[x_] := Sin[x]
n := 50

Ni3[x_] := Sum[(f[k]*(-1)^k)/((x - k)*Gamma[k + 1]*Gamma[n - k + 1]), {k, 0, n}]/
           Sum[(-1)^k/((x - k)*Gamma[k + 1]*Gamma[n - k + 1]), {k, 0, n}]

Plot[{Ni3[x], f[x]}, {x, -7, 7}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> 10]
```

At number of terms n below 40 the plot gives what is expected. But when increasing it above 50 the plot becomes corrupted. The setting `$MinPrecision` does not affect the result. The series is proven to converge to $f(x)=\sin(x)$.

[image: bad plot]

Comment: Try using a high value of `WorkingPrecision` in `Plot`, e.g. `WorkingPrecision -> 60`.

Comment: @Szabolcs you made incorrect change to the expression, putting one sum inside the other

Comment: @Szabolcs re Working Precision - thanks, it worked.

Comment: Sorry about that. When you paste expressions like this, select them, right click, then use Copy As -> Input Form.

Comment: @Szabolcs I did exactly that. It is what exported as Input Form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Szabolcs suggests, cranking up `WorkingPrecision` (or for that matter, just forcing `Plot[]` to use arbitrary precision) helps a lot. In this answer, I've taken the liberty to slightly simplify your [barycentric interpolant](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0036144502417715) as well:

```
f[x_] := Sin[x]

Ni3[n_Integer, x_] := (x - n) Binomial[x, n]
    Sum[(-1)^(n - k) Binomial[n, k] f[k]/(x - k), {k, 0, n}, Method -> "Procedural"]

Plot[{Ni3[50, x], f[x]}, {x, -7, 7}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
     PlotRange -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image: sine and barycentric interpolant]

Comment: How to force it to use arbitrary precision?

Comment: You get this plot with `WorkingPrecision -> 20`?  I get junk with that ... I needed a much higher value.

Comment: @Szabolcs, well, I simplified OP's function a bit; that helped.

Comment: @Anixx, as I said, with `WorkingPrecision`.

Comment: To be precise, it runs out of precision around 1.5 for a precision setting of 20, around -1.2 for 30, and looks fine for 40 (for default plot range).

Comment: @J.M. Ah, I see now.

Comment: @Anixx If you use an explicit WorkingPrecision setting, Mathematica will use its arbitrary precision arithmetic.  This doesn't mean that it will use "infinitely many" digits.  It'll start with as many digits as you ask for in WorkingPrecision, and it'll try to keep track of how much error accumulates during the calculations.  It might run out of precision.  Try e.g. your original `Ni3` with ``Ni3[1.1`20]``.  It'll give you "zero", with a pink background. You can apply `Precision` to it to verify that it has none.

Comment: @Szabolcs, actually, now that I tried it out, `WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision` works, too. >:)

Comment: @J.M. `WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision` doesn't though.

Comment: What about WorkingPrecision -> $MaxNumber?

Comment: @Szabolcs, true. That's the cancellation inherent in computing high-degree barycentric interpolants at play. I'm surprised just forcing arbitrary precision and a modest number of digits to work with made for something reasonable.

Comment: @Anixx, what for? You could try it out yourself; I won't.

Comment: It seems your Lagrange form does not work faster though...

Comment: @J.M. `WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision` often works in this situation because switching on significance arithmetic is enough for precision tracking and `$MaxExtraPrecision` to be able to take care of the rest.

Comment: @Oleksandr, [I know.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=6207310#6207310) ;)